# Google Places API : refresh Place IDs with Java

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Google [warns us](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/place-id#save-id) about PlaceID changes and suggests;

> Place IDs may change due to large-scale updates on the Google Maps database. In such cases, a place may receive a new place ID, and the old ID returns a NOT_FOUND response.
>
> You can refresh Place IDs free of charge, by making a Place Details request, specifying only the ID field in the fields parameter.

Unfortunately, there is no sample code for Java/Kotlin on their website except a link to their [web services](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsRequests)

```
String placeID ="Some place ID";

    List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(
            Place.Field.ID,
    );

    // Construct a request object, passing the place ID and fields array.
    FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.builder(placeID, placeFields).build();
    placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
        Place place = response.getPlace();

        if (!placeID.equals(place.getId())) {
            //update your old placeID
        }
   }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
        if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
            //Place removed.
        }
   });
```

Is this a porper way to update a placeIDs with Java?

Comment: Your code looks fine as far as I can see. As long as you only add the place ID in the requested fields, you should only trigger the Places Details - ID Refresh SKU. Is this code working for you? I recommend you test it with an invalid place ID. Please share the results of the testing from your side.

Comment: @evan I shared my own result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested my databases and found a case where the update occurs. The below code contains both a renewed placeID, removed placeID, and still valid palceID so that one can test.

```
ArrayList<String> placeIDsList = new ArrayList<>();
placeIDsList.add("ChIJTaKjynxesBQREvi1CU5QUFg");
placeIDsList.add("EjhDdW1odXJpeWV0IE1haGFsbGVzaSwgVXp1biBTay4sIEV6aW5lL8OHYW5ha2thbGUsIFR1cmtleSIuKiwKFAoSCakQkmN8XrAUEVkLpNK_F4IJEhQKEgmFzKyYe16wFBGSjU7F2ooIIg");
placeIDsList.add("hIJy9YVxdxpsBQRq0-xUVJdZQ8");

// Specify the fields to return (in this example all fields are returned).
List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID);

for (String plc : placeIDsList ) {
    // Construct a request object, passing the place ID and fields array.
    FetchPlaceRequest request = FetchPlaceRequest.builder(plc, placeFields).build();

    Log.e(TAG,"request for place with ID = " + plc);

    placesClient.fetchPlace(request).addOnSuccessListener((response) -> {
        Place place = response.getPlace();


        if (!plc.equals(place.getId())) {
            Log.e(TAG,"placeID renewed");
            Log.e(TAG,"placeID old = " + plc);
            Log.e(TAG,"placeID new = " + place.getId());

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Place found: " + place.getId());
        }


    }).addOnFailureListener((exception) -> {
        if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
            ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
            int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
            // Handle error with given status code.
            Log.e(TAG, "Place with ID "+plc+" not found");
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception message is :" + exception.getMessage());
            Log.e(TAG, "Status code = " + statusCode);
        }
    });
}
```

The output is

```
E/MapsActivity: request for place with ID = ChIJTaKjynxesBQREvi1CU5QUFg
E/MapsActivity: request for place with ID = jhDdW1odXJpeWV0IE1haGFsbGVzaSwgVXp1biBTay4sIEV6aW5lL8OHYW5ha2thbGUsIFR1cmtleSIuKiwKFAoSCakQkmN8XrAUEVkLpNK_F4IJEhQKEgmFzKyYe16wFBGSjU7F2ooIIg
E/MapsActivity: request for place with ID = hIJy9YVxdxpsBQRq0-xUVJdZQ8
E/MapsActivity: placeID renewed
E/MapsActivity: placeID old = EjhDdW1odXJpeWV0IE1haGFsbGVzaSwgVXp1biBTay4sIEV6aW5lL8OHYW5ha2thbGUsIFR1cmtleSIuKiwKFAoSCakQkmN8XrAUEVkLpNK_F4IJEhQKEgmFzKyYe16wFBGSjU7F2ooIIg
E/MapsActivity: placeID new = Ei5DdW1odXJpeWV0LCBVenVuIFNrLiwgRXppbmUvw4dhbmFra2FsZSwgVHVya2V5Ii4qLAoUChIJqRCSY3xesBQRWQuk0r8XggkSFAoSCYXMrJh7XrAUEZKNTsXaiggi
E/MapsActivity: Place with ID hIJy9YVxdxpsBQRq0-xUVJdZQ8 not found
E/MapsActivity: Exception message is :9012: INVALID_REQUEST
E/MapsActivity: Status code = 9012
E/MapsActivity: Place found: ChIJTaKjynxesBQREvi1CU5QUFg
```

And it seems that the `status code 9102` is for place not found.